# array to variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables, loops

I'm programming in PHP and I have a huge array which contains a lot of ID's. I need all these ID's to be variables so I can use these in another function. I have done a lot of research on loops in PHP but I can find one which "converts" the arrays into variables that I can use in another function. So far I have a `foreach` loop which processes the whole array and divided into `$persons`. But when I use `$persons` in the next function it only uses the last array. My code is as follows:

```
$retrieved_id_array=explode(",",$retrieved_id_string);

foreach($retrieved_id_array as $persons)
    $retrieved_string=file_get_contents("https://HDXLfansite.com/$persons");
```

So the problem is how do I make a loop which provides me with several variables I can use in another function? Or should I use another method/code?

Comment: That's what [`extract()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) does, but consider if you _really_ need them as variables. You can absolutely pass array elements into functions.  `callfunction($array['arg1'], $array['arg99'])`. Much nicer than filling up your namespace with a bunch of one time use variables.

Comment: Cant you call the function inside the foreach? so you only need the current array only? How many varibles with Ids are you planing to use? I think the correct path is to use the foreach with a call of the funcition inside for each element of the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thats because you are overwriting your variable `$retrieved_string` in loop, you could do:

```
foreach($retrieved_id_array as $persons) {
   //add it in array
    $retrieved_string[] =file_get_contents("https://HDXLfansite.com/$persons");
}
```